# how to deploy simple boost program written in visual studio on other computers

Tags: c++, boost, static-libraries

I have written a simple program in C++ that uses the boost filesystem library to organize some files. I am using the Visual Studio 2013 Express for Windows Desktop IDE. I would like my program to run on other computers without an installer or anything else. The user should be able to just download the program and click on it.

I built my program in Release mode and it works on my computer. When I tried to deploy on another computer, the error I got was MSVCP120.dll is missing. To fix this I right-clicked on my project, clicked properties, then Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Code Generation, and I changed the Runtime Library from Multi-threaded DLL (/MD) to Multi-threaded (/MT). Now my program won't compile properly because of this build error:

> Error 1   error LNK1104: cannot open file
>   'libboost_filesystem-vc120-mt-s-1_55.lib' C:\Users\inspection\Desktop\sortFile\Project1\Project1\LINK Project1

I looked in the following folder:

> C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_55_0\libs\filesystem\build\msvc-12.0\release\link-static\threading-multi

and I could not find *libboost_filesystem-vc120-mt-s-1_55.lib*, though I could find *libboost_filesystem-vc120-mt-1_55.lib*. The file names are close, they only differ by an '-s' term located after the '-mt' term.

How can I statically link the boost filesystem library so that my whole program runs as a standalone executable, without another user having to install anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boost needs to be recompiled to match your new runtime library setting. The filename of the Boost library indicates the settings it was linked with, and the Boost auto-link code automatically updated the needed filename to match your new settings. In this case, it quite accurately indicates that you need a Boost lib which was compiled with a static stdlib link.

Comment: How do I compile a Boost lib with a static stdlib link? Does that mean I will need to rebuild Boost entirely? (the really long build from the command window which builds the entire boost library, that takes about 20 minutes? - not complaining just trying to make sure I understand exactly which process is required)